# C# Fixture OmitAutoProperties

Tags: c#, autofixture

Is there any way to use `OmitAutoProperties` except entity.Id (Key) and only User.Id (ForeignKey)?

```
var user = new Fixture().Build<User>().Create();
var entity = new Fixture().Build<Game>().With(x => x.User, user).Create();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `With`:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var user = fixture
           .Build<User>()
           .OmitAutoProperties()
           .With(p => p.Id)
           .Create();

var entity = fixture
             .Build<Game>()
             .OmitAutoProperties()
             .With(p => p.Id)
             .With(p => p.User, user)
             .Create();
```